# With GNU Make, how can I combine multiple files into one?

Tags: makefile

I have some SQL files that I would like to process with `sed` and concatenate into a single file. Is there a slick way to do this with a single GNU Make recipe?

If I know the set of files at the time that I'm writing the Makefile, I could just write a multi-line recipe.

```
combined.sql: main.sql table1.sql table2.sql
    sed -e 's/latin1/utf8/' main.sql > $@
    sed -e 's/latin1/utf8/' table1.sql >> $@
    sed -e 's/latin1/utf8/' table2.sql >> $@
```

This seems too repetitious, and also won't be workable if I have a dynamically generated list of input files. How can I nicely do this in a minimally-redundant way that can extend to an arbitrary number of input files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the fact that you have an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for your prerequisites and the fact that `sed` takes arbitrarily many input files you get:

```
combined.sql: main.sql table1.sql table2.sql
    sed -e 's/latin1/utf8/' $^ > $@
```

For the general case of a tool that doesn't take multiple file inputs you can still use `$^` in a shell loop:

```
combined.sql: main.sql table1.sql table2.sql
    for file in $^; do \
        some_other_tool $$file; \
    done > $@
```

Comment: The first form is exactly what I ended up using. I like the idea of using a shell `for` loop in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
cat *.sql | sed -e 's/latin1/utf8/' > output.sql
```

You can but that in to a shell script and have it take file name parameters etc. if you like.

Comment: No need for `cat` as `sed` takes multiple input files. No need for an external script either as that can just go right in the rule body.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. In this case I can just pass all the filenames to `sed` at once. I still wonder about the general case, if I needed to use a tool that did not accept multiple inputs on one command line.

Comment: I would "just" make a script that took the files as arguments and looped through them.

Comment: There is *no reason* to make an external script though. Well, only if the contents of the script are long and complicated and would be unreadable with the necessary makefile escaping. A make recipe body *is* a script (well multiple scripts).

Comment: You are correct. Sometimes though, I don't have `make` on the machine that needs to *do stuff*

Comment: Yes, but this is specifically talking about the case where he is *already using* make.